# Crypt Decrypt password fails

Tags: java, encryption, password-encryption

I can't understand why this code fails raising exception with the input **bnlbnl18** and not with other values:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
/**
 * 
 * @param password
 * @return
 * @throws AuthException 
 */
public static String encryptPassword(String password) throws AuthException{
    byte[] textEncrypted = "".getBytes();
    try{

        DESKeySpec keySpec = new DESKeySpec(Constants.DESkey);
        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
        SecretKey myDesKey = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);

        Cipher desCipher;

        // Create the cipher 
        //desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

        AlgorithmParameterSpec alogrithm_specs = new IvParameterSpec(Constants.DESkey);

        // Initialize the cipher for encryption
        desCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myDesKey, alogrithm_specs);

        //sensitive information
        byte[] text = password.getBytes();

        // Encrypt the text
        textEncrypted = desCipher.doFinal(text);

    }catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("[AUTH] Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the encryption phase\n" + e.getMessage());
        throw new AuthException("Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the encryption phase");
    }catch(NoSuchPaddingException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("[AUTH] Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the encryption phase\n" + e.getMessage());
        throw new AuthException("Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the encryption phase");
    }catch(InvalidKeyException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("[AUTH] Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the encryption phase\n" + e.getMessage());
        throw new AuthException("Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the encryption phase");
    }catch(IllegalBlockSizeException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("[AUTH] Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the encryption phase\n" + e.getMessage());
        throw new AuthException("Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the encryption phase");
    }catch(BadPaddingException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("[AUTH] Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the encryption phase\n" + e.getMessage());
        throw new AuthException("Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the encryption phase");
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("[AUTH] Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the encryption phase\n" + e.getMessage());
        throw new AuthException("Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the encryption phase");
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("[AUTH] Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the encryption phase\n" + e.getMessage());
        throw new AuthException("Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the encryption phase");
    } 

    return new String(textEncrypted);

}   
public static String decryptPassword(String passwordToDecrypt) throws AuthException{

    DESKeySpec keySpec;
    byte[] textDecrypted = "".getBytes();
    try {
        keySpec = new DESKeySpec(Constants.DESkey);

        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
        SecretKey myDesKey = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);

        Cipher desCipher;

        AlgorithmParameterSpec alogrithm_specs = new IvParameterSpec(Constants.DESkey);

        // Create the cipher 
        //desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

        // Initialize the same cipher for decryption
        desCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, myDesKey, alogrithm_specs);

        // Decrypt the text
        byte[] passwordToDecryptByte = passwordToDecrypt.getBytes();



       textDecrypted = desCipher.doFinal(passwordToDecryptByte);

    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("[AUTH] Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the encryption phase\n" + e.getMessage());
        throw new AuthException("Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the decryption phase");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("[AUTH] Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the encryption phase\n" + e.getMessage());
        throw new AuthException("Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the decryption phase");
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("[AUTH] Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the encryption phase\n" + e.getMessage());
        throw new AuthException("Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the decryption phase");
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("[AUTH] Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the encryption phase\n" + e.getMessage());
        throw new AuthException("Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the decryption phase");
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("[AUTH] Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the encryption phase\n" + e.getMessage());
        throw new AuthException("Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the decryption phase");
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the encryption phase\n" + e.getMessage());
        throw new AuthException("Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the decryption phase");
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("[AUTH] Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the encryption phase\n" + e.getMessage());
        throw new AuthException("Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the decryption phase");
    }

    return new String(textDecrypted);

}


public static void main(String[] args) throws AuthException, UnsupportedEncodingException{
    String password = URLEncoder.encode(encryptPassword("bnlbnl18"), "UTF-8");

    System.out.println("\"" + URLDecoder.decode(password, "UTF-8") + "\"" + decryptPassword(URLDecoder.decode(password,"UTF-8")));

}
```

And this is the exception

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:811)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:676)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.DESCipher.engineDoFinal(DESCipher.java:314)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2087)
    ...
```

I think I miss something. It's strange as behaviour. Do you have any ideas? Is it wrong the "DES" solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm mistaken but I believe DES is no longer a secure system.  I think you should look into AES?

Comment: And the exception stack trace is? And the endrypt method is?

Comment: 1. Where is the decryptPassword method? 2. DO NOT use URLEncoder and URLDecoder. Use base 64 encoding and decoding for encrypted data.

Comment: Sorry, editing I miss the encryptPassword. However, don't focus on the type of encryption if it isn't the problem. I thank for the advice but now I'm worried about the exception.

Comment: And what is the exception? Don't you think this should be the starting point to identify what is wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't be encrypting and particularly decrypting passwords at all. This is radically insecure and has ***major*** legal consequences for your company's transactions. You should be securely hashing them, and comparing the hashes for checking purposes.

Comment: @EJP you are right but the DES is enough for my aim. JB Nizet: Yes, I edit the question but I think the best way is to try the code to understand why with different password it changes the behaviour

Comment: As long as you and your lawyers understand that transactions executed by the protected system aren't non-repudiable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JB Nizet : following your instructions, here the code

```
/**
 * 
 * @param password
 * @return
 * @throws AuthException 
 * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException 
 */
public static String encryptPassword(String password) throws AuthException, UnsupportedEncodingException{
    byte[] textEncrypted = "".getBytes();
    try{

        DESKeySpec keySpec = new DESKeySpec(Constants.DESkey);
        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
        SecretKey myDesKey = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);

        Cipher desCipher;

        // Create the cipher 
        desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

        AlgorithmParameterSpec alogrithm_specs = new IvParameterSpec(Constants.DESkey);

        // Initialize the cipher for encryption
        desCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myDesKey, alogrithm_specs);

        //sensitive information
        byte[] text = password.getBytes("UTF-8");

        // Encrypt the text
        textEncrypted = desCipher.doFinal(text);

    }catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("[AUTH] Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the encryption phase\n" + e.getMessage());
        throw new AuthException("Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the encryption phase");
    }catch(NoSuchPaddingException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("[AUTH] Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the encryption phase\n" + e.getMessage());
        throw new AuthException("Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the encryption phase");
    }catch(InvalidKeyException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("[AUTH] Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the encryption phase\n" + e.getMessage());
        throw new AuthException("Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the encryption phase");
    }catch(IllegalBlockSizeException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("[AUTH] Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the encryption phase\n" + e.getMessage());
        throw new AuthException("Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the encryption phase");
    }catch(BadPaddingException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("[AUTH] Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the encryption phase\n" + e.getMessage());
        throw new AuthException("Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the encryption phase");
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("[AUTH] Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the encryption phase\n" + e.getMessage());
        throw new AuthException("Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the encryption phase");
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("[AUTH] Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the encryption phase\n" + e.getMessage());
        throw new AuthException("Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the encryption phase");
    } 

    return BaseEncoding.base64().encode(textEncrypted);

}   

/**
 * 
 * @param passwordDecrypted
 * @return
 * @throws AuthException 
 * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException 
 */

public static String decryptPassword(String passwordToDecrypt) throws AuthException, UnsupportedEncodingException{

    DESKeySpec keySpec;
    byte[] textDecrypted = "".getBytes();
    try {
        keySpec = new DESKeySpec(Constants.DESkey);

        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
        SecretKey myDesKey = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);

        Cipher desCipher;

        AlgorithmParameterSpec alogrithm_specs = new IvParameterSpec(Constants.DESkey);

        // Create the cipher 
        //desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

        // Initialize the same cipher for decryption
        desCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, myDesKey, alogrithm_specs);

        // Decrypt the text
        byte[] passwordToDecryptByte = BaseEncoding.base64().decode(passwordToDecrypt);

       textDecrypted = desCipher.doFinal(passwordToDecryptByte);

    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("[AUTH] Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the encryption phase\n" + e.getMessage());
        throw new AuthException("Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the decryption phase");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("[AUTH] Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the encryption phase\n" + e.getMessage());
        throw new AuthException("Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the decryption phase");
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("[AUTH] Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the encryption phase\n" + e.getMessage());
        throw new AuthException("Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the decryption phase");
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("[AUTH] Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the encryption phase\n" + e.getMessage());
        throw new AuthException("Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the decryption phase");
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("[AUTH] Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the encryption phase\n" + e.getMessage());
        throw new AuthException("Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the decryption phase");
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the encryption phase\n" + e.getMessage());
        throw new AuthException("Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the decryption phase");
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("[AUTH] Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the encryption phase\n" + e.getMessage());
        throw new AuthException("Auth Exception...there is something wrong at the decryption phase");
    }

    return new String(textDecrypted);


}


public static void main(String[] args) throws AuthException, UnsupportedEncodingException{
    String password = encryptPassword("testtest19");

    System.out.println(password + " --> " + "\"" + decryptPassword(password)+ "\"");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're transforming a byte array, containing any kind of byte, into a String, using

```
new String(bytes);
```

This constructor expects the bytes to represent characters transformed to bytes using your default platform encoding, and it has a very good chance of not being the case. Don't use String to represent binary data? Leave it as a byte array. Or encode the byte array using Hex or Base64 encoding.

Comment: But I have to set it into a cookie that needs a string. So do I have to encode it using Base64 and then create the String?

Comment: Yes. Base64 encoding transforms any byte array into a string containing printable, ascii characters, that can be used inside a cookie value.

Comment: Mmm ok I try this solution

Comment: It works because the generated bytes happen to be a valid representation of a string in your default encoding. I repeat: base64 encoding takes a byte array as argument, and returns a printable String. See http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/BaseEncoding.html#encode%28byte[]%29 for example.

Comment: using "import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;" and changing the main like this `System.out.println("\"" + URLDecoder.decode(password, "UTF-8") + "\"" + new String(Base64.decodeBase64(decryptPassword(URLDecoder.decode(password,"UTF-8")))));` it doesn't work. Do I fail something?

Comment: What you must replace is the call to `new String(textEncrypted)`. Instead, it should base64-encode `textEncrypted`. And of course, in the decrypt method, you must also replace `passwordToDecrypt.getBytes()` by base64 decoding of `passwordToDecrypt`. And stop using URLEncoder/URLDecoder. It's completely useless.

Comment: I changed my main method to aim what you said (I haven't changed the decrypt method): I encrypt `String password = encryptPassword(new String(Base64.encodeBase64("bnlbnl18".getBytes())));` and then decrypt `System.out.println("\"" + new String(Base64.decodeBase64(decryptPassword(password)))+ "\"");`. It works! Do you find some advice in those code lines? Thanks a lot

Comment: Another thing...if I use a Base64 encode I see that there is the / char...Are you sure I haven't to use URLEncode to avoit problem with cookie? I know...it is a stupid question :-)

Comment: Why don't you do it like I advise you to do it? Now you're not encrypting the password. You're encrypting the base64 encoding of the password. It's incorrect. You need to 1. transform the password to bytes (`using getBytes("UTF8")`), 2. encrypt this byte array, which produces an encrypted byte array, 3. base64-encode this encrypted byte array to produce a printable string.

Comment: On the other side, you need 1. to base64-decode the base64-encoded-encrypted password to get back the encrypted password as a byte array, 2. to decrypt the encrypted byte array to get back the clear-text byte array, 3. to recreate a String from the byte array using new String(bytes, "UTF8").

Comment: Ok I hope this is what you said: 1) in the encryption method I added `byte[] text = password.getBytes("UTF-8");`  and I return `return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(textEncrypted));`. At the decryption phase (without changing,but I will do) `System.out.println(password + " --> " + "\"" + decryptPassword( new String(Base64.decodeBase64(password)))+ "\"");`. Now is how you said?

Comment: Please post your new complete code by editing your question. The code should be symmetric. If the encryption method deals with the base64 encoding after encryption, then the decrypt method should deal with the base64 decoding before decryption. And you should use encodeBase64String() (which encodes a byte[] to a String), and decodeBase64() (which decodes a String to a byte[]). Or better, you should use Guava instead of apache commons-codec, which is a horrible mess.